# WooCommerce - Email and Post/Zip code validation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of how exactly WooCommerce validates emails, and also how they validate post and zipcodes.

I'm currently using the following code to display in-line messages for any required fields that haven't been filled:

```
function  CheckoutFieldsInlineError( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
  if ( strpos( $field, '</label>') !== false && $args['required'] ) {
    $error = '<span class="error" style="display:none">';
    $error .= sprintf( __('%s is a required field.','woocommerce' ), $args['label'] );
    $error .= '</span>';
    $field = substr_replace( $field, $error, strpos( $field,'</p>'),0);
  }
return $field;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field','CheckoutFieldsInlineError',99,4);
```

however, if the email address HAS been filled, but it's filled with something like "as@a.", the form-row wrapper still has the valid woocommerce class, 'woocommerce-validated', see screenshot:

[image: Attached screenshot showing valid woocommerce class even though the field is actually invalid.]

Likewise, there seems to be a similar sort of validation going on for postcodes and zipcodes, I'm not sure if these run on a per country basis, or only for the UK and US, but it would be good to get clarification on how they work, and also, if there's anyway we can hook into these using a function, so we can display the error messages inline with the fields.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Validate E-Mail https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js#L227-L238

Comment: There is a JS file in your plugin directory that handles the validation. mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js and mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.min.js as for how exactly it validates the zip code I'm not 100% but as linked by Howard that's the git to the file I linked conveniently already highlighting the regex for the email

Comment: did some testing in a WooCommerce website I created and looks like postal code is just checking if not empty likely due to the vastly different postal code formats over the world

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I've now tracked down and overridden the checkout.js, which allows me to display an 'email not valid' error in realtime.

I still can't find the post/zipcode validation, there seems to be some validation inside class_wc_validation that has an is_postcode() function, however, i can't seem to figure out how I  can run some code to display an error message under the postcode. 

Postcode does include validation for just a required field, but it also runs some extra regex validation based on country. 

woocommerce_validate_postcode might be the hook?